# Init script partially launches java app

Tags: java, init-script, init

I have a java application that I manage to execute by hand. The application normally opens several ports for local communications (7180 => 7183). Port 7182 serves as a web console and allows me to quickly check that everything went fine.

```
java -cp $ARCHIVES -Djava.security.policy=$POLICY -Dconfigfile=$CONFIG_FILE $CLASS
```

As soon as I put this in an init script, the ports are not open but the app somehow manages to start with the following message: 'Dead or echo port not responding'.

Here is the start-stop-daemon line in my init script:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --chuid thomas --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
    $DAEMON_ARGS \
```

What difference between manual execution and scripted execution could explain that the app is half started?

---

As an additionnal information, the application is [SIPS Office Server](http://www.sips-atos.com/en/12/About/How-does-it-work-.html) (payment solution).

Comment: Are you running it as a designated user in both cases or as yourself when it works, and root during init?

Comment: I guess init script runs the daemon as root unless you specify it with --chuid username, which I tried. It works when I run the java command line directly from my user thomas, but not when I --chuid thomas from init script.

Comment: Can you share the entire init script? Also what's the distro?

Comment: Here you can find an anonymized version of the script: http://pastebin.com/4z5vvMC5 - please note that I am working on this script in the lab environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted your approach looks OK. I found an example init script that uses the following line:

```
start-stop-daemon --oknodo --start --quiet --chuid $USER --pidfile $PIDFILE \
    --exec $DAEMON -- --pid-file $PIDFILE
```

This is directly out of the file: `/etc/init.d/speech-dispatcher`.

I'd pay special attention to the `pidfile` and might even direct it manually to a path that you're absolutely positive that user `thomas` has read/write access to just to make sure that your problem isn't a permissions problem.

Comment: I indeed checked that the pidfile was correctly created, which is the case. I should have said that when I test the init script, I launch it with such a command line: nohup ./my_script start >> myscript.log